# Как установить Chart.js локально

Tags: диаграммы, chart.js

мне нужно установить Chart.js локально, делаю через GitHab,клонирую от суда https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js
Клонирование проходит успешно, папка появляется, но после того как перехожу в папку Chart.js и пытаюсь установить зависимости через npm (использую команду: npm install) выходит сообщение об ошибке, что npm не смог разрешить зависимость в проекте из-за конфликта с другими версиями зависимостей.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVEnpm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! npm ERR! While resolving: chart.js@4.4.2
npm ERR! Found: rollup@3.29.4npm ERR! node_modules/rollup
npm ERR!   dev rollup@"^3.3.0" from the root projectnpm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:npm ERR! peer rollup@"^2.0.0" from rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/rollup-plugin-tersernpm ERR!   dev rollup-plugin-terser@"^7.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-depsnpm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:npm ERR! C:\Users\pakap\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-03T17_05_18_490Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\pakap\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-03T17_05_18_490Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chart.js (и многие другие библиотеки) можно установить напрямую через npm без необходимости вручную клонировать репозиторий, устанавливать и подключать зависимости.

Просто выполните эту команду в корне своего проекта:

```sh
npm install chart.js
```

Дальнейшие инструкции по использованию библиотеки можно найти на официальном сайте: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/